# How to Hide Bcc option with my mail id in Message Ui framework

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

How to hide Bcc with my mail id .when the user sent mail to my app how should i attach bcc with my mail id with out knowing the end user .

is this possible in message UI framework .any one guide me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no its not possible with the message ui framework. your app may get rejected if you use some private api to do this. you can create a view with form and send this data on server to send mails here you can add your email id for BCC. thats the only option you have